# Adding extra php parameters for sql

Tags: php

So im making a mini webpage that has 8 links, 4 for males and 4 for females in which each has 2 pants and 2 pants. Now ive made 5 php pages and scripted them, but the males shirts and pants do not work. Does anyone know what I can do to make them work?  Ill post my teedetails.php page code and the listoftees.php page code since both pants pages are basically the samething.

teedetails:

```
<?php
    $selection = $_GET["id"];
    mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
    mysql_select_db("clothesshop");
    $sql = "select * from tshirts where tid=$selection;";
    $result = mysql_query($sql);
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="boilerplate.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="teedetails.css">
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale = 1.0,maximum-scale = 1.0">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="primaryContainer" class="primaryContainer clearfix">
            <div id="box" class="clearfix">
                <img id="image" src="img/300-lacoste_logo.png" class="image" />
            </div>
            <div id="box2" class="clearfix">
                <p id="text5">
                    <a id="textspan" href="listoftees.php?g=Women&c=everyday tees">Everyday Tees </a><br />
                </p>
                <p id="text6">
                    <a id="textspan1" href="listoftees.php?g=Women&c=fashion tees">Fashion Tees </a><br />
                </p>
                <p id="text7">
                    <a id="textspan2" href="listofpants.php?g=Women&c=corduroy pants">Corduroy Pants</a><br />
                </p>
                <p id="text8">
                    <a id="textspan3" href="listofpants.php?g=Women&c=artist pants">Artist Pants </a><br />
                </p>
            </div>
            <div id="box3" class="clearfix">
                <p id="text9">
                    Men
                </p>
            </div>

            <div id="box4" class="clearfix">
                <p id="text16">
                    <a id="textspan4" href="listoftees.php?g=Men&c=long sleeve tees">Long Sleeve Tees </a><br />
                </p>
                <p id="text17">
                    <a id="textspan5" href="listoftees.php?g=Men&c=fashion tees">Fashion Tees</a><br />
                </p>
                <p id="text18">
                    <a id="textspan6" href="listofpants.php?g=Men&c=original straight pants">Original Straight Pants</a><br />
                </p>
                <p id="text19">
                    <a id="textspan7" href="listofpants.php?g=Men&c=cargo pants">Cargo Pants</a><br />
                </p>
            </div>
            <article>
                <h1><?php echo $row["tname"]; ?> // <?php echo number_format($row["tprice"], 2); ?>;</h1>
                <img src="img/<?php echo $row["tbig"]; ?>" alt="">
            <p id="text14"><?php echo $row["tdesc"]; ?></p>
            <p>
                <span class="infohdr">Category:</span><?php echo $row["tcat"]; ?>
                <span class="infohdr">Colors:</span><?php echo $row["tcolors"]; ?>
                <span class="infohdr">Sizes:</span><?php echo $row["tsizes"]; ?>
            </p>
        </article>
    </div>
</body>
```

listoftees.php:
"

```
<?php
    $gen = $_GET["g"];
    $cat = $_GET["c"];
    mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
    mysql_select_db("clothesshop");
    $sql = "select * from tshirts where tgender='$gen' and tcat='$cat';";
    $result = mysql_query($sql);
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="boilerplate.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="listoftees.css">
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale = 1.0,maximum-scale = 1.0">
    </head>
<body>
    <div id="primaryContainer" class="primaryContainer clearfix">
        <div id="box" class="clearfix">
            <img id="image" src="img/300-lacoste_logo.png" class="image" />
        </div>
        <div id="box2" class="clearfix">
            <p id="text5">
                <a id="textspan" href="listoftees.php?g=Women&c=everyday t shirt">Everyday Tees </a><br />
            </p>
            <p id="text6">
                <a id="textspan1" href="listoftees.php?g=Women&c=fashion T shirt">Fashion Tees </a><br />
            </p>
            <p id="text7">
                <a id="textspan2" href="listofpants.php?g=Women&c=corduroy pants">Corduroy Pants</a><br />
            </p>
            <p id="text8">
                <a id="textspan3" href="listofpants.php?g=Women&c=artist pants">Artist Pants </a><br />
            </p>
        </div>
        <div id="box3" class="clearfix">
            <p id="text9">
                Men
            </p>
        </div>
        <div id="box4" class="clearfix">
            <p id="text16">
                <a id="textspan4" href="listoftees.php?g=Men&c=long sleeve">Long Sleeve Tees </a><br />
            </p>
            <p id="text17">
                <a id="textspan5" href="listoftees.php?g=Men&c=fashion t shirt">Fashion Tees</a><br />
            </p>
            <p id="text18">
                <a id="textspan6" href="listofpants.php?g=Men&c=original straight pants">Original Straight Pants</a><br />
            </p>
            <p id="text19">
                <a id="textspan7" href="listofpants.php?g=Men&c=cargo pants">Cargo Pants</a><br />
            </p>
        </div>
        <?php while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {?>
            <article>
                <a href="teedetails.php?id=<?php echo $row ["tid"]; ?>">
                <img id="image3" src="img/<?php echo $row ["tsmall"]; ?>" class="image" />
                <h2 class="itemname"><a href="teedetails.php?id=<php echo $row ["tid"]; ?>"><?php echo $row ["tname"]; ?>"></h2></a>
                <h3 class="price">$<?php echo number_format($row["tprice"], 2); ?>"></h3>
                <p class="desc"><?php echo $row ["tdesc"]; ?>"></p>
            </article>
        <?php } ?>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

And yes there was a women's tag. but it didn't work on this site for some reason, the div id is box1 and text 1

Comment: mysql functions are deprecated, upgrade to PDO or MySQLI, i would suggest PDO.

Comment: first error i see is here `$sql = "select * from tshirts where tid=$selection;";`  you have a ; in your select statement as well as `SELECT` needs to be capitalized and so does `FROM` & `WHERE`. Now that I read through your code you have alot of errors. With this code you are vulnerable to SQL Injection attacks.

Comment: You don't need to give us all the junk between the doctype and the starting body-tag. Provide only the neccessarry pieces of code. (formatted, if possible)

Comment: @rackemup420 The semi colon does not cause a problem! There is no requirement to use uppercase `select` / `from` / `where`

Comment: @RiggsFolly is correct, no idea why rackemup420's comment was upvoted

Comment: sorry wrote it real quick didn't mean to put needs, meant should as it good practice to use uppercase for reading purposes

Comment: _but the males shirts and pants do not work_ **is a bit vague** what does not work, have you looked at any error logs? Does anything appaer on the screen? Do you get partial data or NO data?

Comment: Mike, please read [The Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [How do I ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) Please remember we are not **clarevoyant** and we cannot see **over your shoulder**